# Loop through array with LESS - Modify values - Get new array

Tags: arrays, loops, less

I would like to loop through an array, modify each item, and then spit out a new array with the modified items.

I have a strong distaste for foobar examples since they're so abstract.. but it seems strangely applicable here:

note: this is half pseudo code, since I obviously don't know how this would work.

```
.loop (@var)
    @array: (@var + 1), (@var + 2), (@var + 3);
    // outputs @array: var1, var2 var3; (when @var = var)

    .-(@i: length(@array)) when (@i > 0) {
        @item: e(extract(@array, @i));

        @newItem: @item + bar;

    .-((@i - 1));

    @newArray:@newItem,@newItem,@newItem;// ????
).-;

.test {
    .loop ('foo');
}
```

In the above example, calling the loop with foo should output `foo1bar, foo2bar, foo3bar`

Or something... that last bit is the tricky/confusing part. That's probably not how I would access the array, but something like that...

To summarize: I want to pass a single variable through a loop. Within the loop, define an array based on that variable (imagine splitting a single color into separated values). Then using this new array, I want to loop through each item within it, modify it (imagine darkening each value), and then get a new array with those new modified values.

Another example:

```
.loop (@color: red) {
    @separations: red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color);
    // outputs 255, 0, 0

    .-(@i: length (@array)) when (@i > 0) {
        @sep: e(extract(@array, @i));

        @newSep: floor(@sep / 2);
    .-((@i - 1));

    } .-;

    @newArray: @item{i};
    //outputs @newArray: 127, 0, 0;
}
```

And no, I'm not just trying to change the hue of a color. I'm trying to get the relative luminosity of a given color, which requires defining a color, separating it into an array of it's individual rgb values, doing some conditional math to each one, and then getting a new array of those modified values - which then need to be plugged into a formula.

Hope that's vague/detailed enough.

Thanks for any input/advice!

Here's an example of this being achieved in SCSS

```
@function color_luminance($color) {
    // Adapted from: https://github.com/LeaVerou/contrast-ratio/blob/gh-pages/color.js
    // Formula: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef
    $rgba: red($color), green($color), blue($color);
    $rgba2: ();

    @for $i from 1 through 3 {
        $rgb: nth($rgba, $i);
        $rgb: $rgb / 255;

        $rgb: if($rgb < .03928, $rgb / 12.92, pow(($rgb + .055) / 1.055, 2.4));

        $rgba2: append($rgba2, $rgb);
    }

    @return .2126 * nth($rgba2, 1) + .7152 * nth($rgba2, 2) + 0.0722 * nth($rgba2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to implement a function [already existing](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-channel) in Less? (And if you are writing a some other color manipulating function - looping through an array of 3 color channels is the most non-optimal method in Less, explicit code of r, g and b channel variables would be much more clean).

Comment: (Same way it's not evident how string-concatenation like `foo1bar` could help you with a color manipulation(s) (which is pure arithmetic thing and should not involve any string processing). In other words, I could probaby provide an example of such loop, but it does not look like something you're looking for, thus it will be just misleading waste of time).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. No I'm not sure something useful doesn't already exist, but I don't think so. Here's more details on calculating relative luminance: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/relative-luminance.xml  You'll see that it requires conditional calculations be made on each channel, depending on it's value, and then plug the results into a second formula.

Comment: I feel like this should be possible without a loop, but I can't figure out how to get the results of that initial calculation (with guards) back into new variables so they can then be referenced in the formula.  I can easily say `@result:@var1 + @var2;`  But how do I say `@result:@var1 + @var2 when(@var1 > xx);`  And then do it again for the two other channels. That's where I get hung up and figure that logic needs to be stuck into a loop.  It's also been a long day though... lol. Thanks again

Comment: "No I'm not sure something useful doesn't already exist, but I don't think so" - The link above was a gentle hint to never guess ;) : The WCAG2 relative luminance function is available in Less as [`luma`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-channel-luma).

Comment: As for conditionals - in Less they are done via mixins so you'd simply put those formulae into a mixin.

Comment: Yes! And works! I was aware of luminance, but relied on this calculator to test the results: http://springmeier.org/www/contrastcalculator/index.php  The results differed from the luminance function, so I assuming LESS's concepts differed from WCAG and moved on. But after you linked to the docs again, I re-read them and now see luminance is the successor to luma, which is indeed based on the vary same WCAG calculations.  It looks to me like that calculator actually has a bug. If you try #00ff00 it's translating to 255,255,0 which is clearly incorrect! I should have caught that before!

Comment: Thanks again! I'd mark your comment as an answer if I could.

Comment: Well, it would be answer if the Q is "how do I implement *-luminance" in Less. But it's not, so such answer would be misleading for future visitors. There're a few similar Qs (e.g. "how to loop through an array to modify its values and a get new one as result") at SO already, but the trick is that each time an answer is very different depending on use-case/how-the-result-is-supposed-to-be-used, so it's not even easy to mark this as a duplicate. So I'd rather mark the Q as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced".